# Execute code inside visual studio code and replace the executed code with its output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vim, metaprogramming

I usually use some Python code for metaprogramming repetitive part of code. For in stance the output of these expression:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(f"var{i} = myfunc(arg{i})")
```

Would let me to automatize the assignment of some variables:

```
var0 = myfunc(arg0)
var1 = myfunc(arg1)
var2 = myfunc(arg2)
var3 = myfunc(arg3)
var4 = myfunc(arg4)
var5 = myfunc(arg5)
var6 = myfunc(arg6)
var7 = myfunc(arg7)
var8 = myfunc(arg8)
var9 = myfunc(arg9)
```

Ideally, the expected behaviour would be that the selected code would be substituted in the file where is written with its output. In vim there are some [options](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Execute_Python_from_within_current_file). I could not find a similar feature in Visual Studio Code. Below a prototype of the expected behaviour:
[image]

Comment: Have you managed to create this extension (looking at the anim) or is this the requested behavior

Comment: @rioV8 No it's the expected behaviour, I will try to make the extension as soon as I got some spare time

Answer (score 1):

To generate this type of repetitive code you can use [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen).

For the generator expresion use

```
(@var{{=j}} = myfunc\(arg{{=j}}\)){10}
```

It will generate all code on one line, you have to replace the `@` with a line break, you can use multi cursor for that (Select All Occurences - Ctrl+Shift+L)

Supporting a line break in the preview is very tricky.

You can free 10 lines and place a cursor (Add Cursor Down) at the start of each and use the next generator extension

```
var{{=i}} = myfunc\(arg{{=i}}\)
```

Comment: Thanks, however I don't use much regular expression and python allows me to do many tricks that I would not imagine how to do with regex. I

Comment: @GM You can get a Jupyter Notebook running with your generator scripts, execute a script and copy paste the code to your source code

Comment: Yes I do this usually but is not very handy, the vim extension was great for this task it would be great to have something similar for visual studio code

Comment: @GM You can use the HyperSnips extension and write the scripts in JavaScript

Comment: Maybe I could develop an extension on my own as you did, I think should not be too difficult to redirect the output to the clipboard and paste it instead of the highlighted text